# Reference a value type element in an array

Tags: c#

I have a value type `Node` and an array `grid`

```
private Node[,] grid;

public struct Node {
    public byte occupant;
    public Direction toTarget;
    public float distance;
}

public enum Direction {
    UP, LEFT, RIGHT, DOWN
}
```

How do I reference an element instead of copying it on assignment?

Example

```
Node node = grid[0,0];
node.occupant = 1;
```

Doing this copies the value of `grid[0,0]` into `node`. I basically want a pointer into the `grid` array at the point specified so I can modify the Node directly. I'm unable to use `unsafe`.

Is there some syntax sugar for this or do I have to modify directly? ex:

```
grid[0,0].occupant = 1;
```

Comment: Why dont you use `class` instead of `struct` ?

Comment: Will it make a difference?

Comment: It doesn't copy in c#,  It is a reference (pointer).

Comment: Does that mean every element in array has its own heap allocation?

Comment: @PatrickLorio Yes it will work as you expect....

Comment: `class` will not work the same as `struct`. Array of a reference type will be initialized to all nulls. Array of value type will be initialized to all zeros, but contained objects will be there straight up. But it does make sense to ask why `Node` is the value type.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat  struct is immutable, if OP wants a reference to it, then he probably wants to a change a value of a property. A *class* might be a better choice for it...

Comment: `struct` is not immutable, it is rather passed to methods by value, i.e. copied unless method argument is `ref`. Value types are rarely a good choice, though. Examples are game programming, where array of reusable structs avoids garbage collection for entire lifetime of a game. New C# 7 syntax will address precisely that use.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, it's been awhile since I've used C#. It's for a path finding script where I'm going to be looping over and modifying the array quite frequently. I probably could get away with using class, however with a struct I should get better cache performance because all the elements are bunched together in memory.

Comment: @PatrickLorio I would bet on a `class` first and wouldn't think of performance too much unless proven wrong.

Comment: Isn't premature optimization the root of all happiness? Kidding, it's for a hobby project and I don't think I'll be shooting myself in the foot too much using struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be syntax for that in C# 7. Right now, the only way to do that will be to pass the element by ref.

```
class Program
{

    static void Do(ref Node node)
    {
        node.occupant = 1;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Node[] nodes = new Node[10];
        nodes[5].occupant = 2;

        Do(ref nodes[5]);
        Console.WriteLine(nodes[5].occupant);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

}
```

This code segment prints 1, which is the value set in the method Do. That indicates that the method has received a reference to the Node object, rather than a copied value.

Answer (score 1):

```
void DoStuff( ref Node n)
{
    n.occupant = 1;
}
...
DoStuff( ref grid[0,0);
```